# Guidance on adding attributes to KML

Tags: c#, kml, sharpkml

I can plot a path in KML no problems. Now I need to annotate the vertices with speed and heading. I could handle this as a progression of placemarks, but before I proceed I thought it best to see what others do in this scenario.

As it happens I'm using SharpKML in C#, but that's incidental to the question of approach.

So, recommendations?

---

Well, that looks to be it. Placemarks, and possibly gx:Track if you don't mind vendor extensions.

I'm not sure you can annotate individual points in a gx:Track, I haven't tried. Despite this, Jason gets the points for submitting the only answer.

Comment: Off the top of my head I can't think of any way to do it other than Placemarks - interested to see if anyone has another approach!

Comment: I ended up using placemarks but I'll leave the question open for a while to see whether anyone says anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider using the [gx:Track](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#gxtrack) as the geometry for your paths in which the speed and elevation can be shown in the [Elevation profile](http://support.google.com/earth/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=181393).

A good example can be found in this article:
http://google-latlong.blogspot.com/2010/06/relive-your-hiking-biking-and-other.html

For each vertex you have a time-location pair with a *when* for the time and *gx:coord* for the location. You can also add custom metadata at each time-location pair using an *ExtendedData* element with *gx:SimpleArrayData*. See [track example](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#trackexample) with ExtendedData.

```
          <gx:SimpleArrayData name="cadence">
            <gx:value>86</gx:value>
            <gx:value>103</gx:value>
            <gx:value>108</gx:value>
            <gx:value>113</gx:value>
            <gx:value>113</gx:value>
            <gx:value>113</gx:value>
            <gx:value>113</gx:value>
          </gx:SimpleArrayData>
```

If you use the track icon style the heading is dynamically oriented at the current heading as you animate the path.

UPDATE: as Peter commented, the use of the gx: namespace is a Google extension which works fine with Google products but the KML may not work as expected with non-Google products.

Comment: I did use ExtendedData, but on Placemarks. This allowed me to use strictly core KML and stay away from vendor extensions.